# Connecting flight from Johannesburg to Abu Dhabi to Mumbai

Tags: visas

I am a South African citizen. I have a 5-hour wait for my connecting flight in Abu Dhabi. Do I need a visa? I have no intention of leaving the airport. I am flying from Johannesburg to Abu Dhabi to Mumbai.

Comment: Is that a single ticket?